# Machine Learning Text Categorization with Data in multiple Languages

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp

I want to label natural text Dokuments in various different categories (arround 400 different categories) using Neural Networks. I have around 50.000 documents already labeled. The problem is around half of them are english only, the others are either chinese or a mix of chinese and english.

Would it be possible to train a network with all of the documents and get a network with an good quality or is it more useful to separate the languages and train the network with english documents only (arround 20.000 docs then)?